# Using Python fetch remote URL

Tags: python, get

I have a URL http://apache.domain.com/get.php?id=1001

I am new to python and would like python to connect to the url and if returned page is empty then:

```
print("Content Empty")
```

otherwise:

```
print("Has content")
```

Any suggestions on how i can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually trying to find if the page is empty or actually exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`urllib.request` stdlib module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request) to fetch the url:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen

try:
     with urlopen("http://apache.domain.com/get.php?id=1001") as response:
          print("Has content" if response.read(1) else "Content Empty")
except OSError as e:
    print("error happened: {}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [Python Requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://apache.domain.com/get.php?id=1001")
print response.text
```

You can then take the necessary actions depending on what `response.text` contains.

Comment: `response.text` reads all (potentially unlimited) content and tries to decode it into Unicode. It is unnecessary and might be harmful if all you need is to find out whether the page is empty.